# How to use laptop speakers as handsfree / headset for my mobile phone? on windows 10

Tags: laptop, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I past most of my time with my headset on connected to my laptop. Every time I get a call I've to put down my headset and take the call with my phone stuck to my ear.

Is there any way to answer the call on my mobile but hear and talk through my headset? It would be like my laptop acting as a headset.

I just need the mobile phone to recognize my laptop as a headset. I found how to do this with windows 7 but I need this for windows 10.

Thanks in advance.